# Filehandler and consolehandler aren't working properly with logging config

Tags: python, logging, config

I'm having a bit of an issue here. I have set up a scratch py file just to test out my logging. Neither the consoleHandler nor the fileHandler are getting the right output (any output). Can anyone see if they can eyeball any issues? Here is my log config file

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=fileHandler, consoleHandler

[formatters]
keys=simpleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=fileHandler, consoleHandler
formatter=simpleFormatter

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout, )

[handler_fileHandler]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'logging.log'), 'w')

[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

Here is the scratch python file,

```
import logging
from logging import config

LOGGER_NAME = 'Work'
logger = logging.getLogger(LOGGER_NAME)
logging.config.fileConfig('C:\\Users\\cschuma1\\PycharmProjects\\workstuff\\config\\logging.conf')

addition = 'add' + 'ition'
logger.debug('print addition %s', addition)
```

I have looked closely at other's configs on stackoverflow and I believe that I have all of the necessary levels set, and formatter/handler objects, etc. for my task. Does anyone know what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that at least in python 3, the line

```
logging.config.fileConfig('C:\\Users\\cschuma1\\PycharmProjects\\workstuff\\config\\logging.conf')
```

needs to come before,

```
LOGGER_NAME = 'Work'
logger = logging.getLogger(LOGGER_NAME)
```

This is the fixed sample program I had above,

```
import logging
from logging import config

logging.config.fileConfig('C:\\Users\\cschuma1\\PycharmProjects\\workstuff\\config\\logging.conf')
LOGGER_NAME = 'Work'
logger = logging.getLogger(LOGGER_NAME)


addition = 'add' + 'ition'
logger.debug('print addition %s', addition)
```